# Find all positive integer solutions to $24x+18y=6420$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integer solutions to $24x+18y=6420$.

Here's my work.

Simplifying the equation gives $4x+3y=1070$. Note that this equation has solutions because $\gcd (4,3)=1\mid 1070$.

We will use the Euclidean Algorithm to solve $4x+3y=1$.

We have that $$4=3(1)+1\\
3=1(3)$$
Hence $$1=4-3(1)=4(1)-3(1).$$
Hence one solution $(x_0,y_0)$ to the equation is $(1070,-1070)$. We know that all solutions to the equation $4x+3y=1070$ are of the form $(x_0 + \dfrac{b}{d}k, y_0-\dfrac{a}{d}k),$ where $b=3$, $a=4$, $d=\gcd (4,3)=1$, and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, to find all positive integer solutions, we need to solve $1070+4k> 0\;(1)$ and $-1070-3k > 0\;(2)$. Simplifying $(1)$ gives $k >-\dfrac{1070}{4}=-267.5$ and simplifying $(2)$ gives $k<-\dfrac{1070}{3}=-356\dfrac{2}{3}$. Hence, since there is no intersection between the set of solutions to $(1)$ and $(2)$, the equation has no positive solutions.

> Edit: The problem was updated.

Comment: Even if you only require $x,y$ to be non-negative, it is clear that there are no solutions.  $x$ clearly has to be $0$, $y=1$ doesn't work, and $y=2$ is too big.

Comment: There is most likely something wrong with the question. I got it from a university textbook. It should not have such an elementary solution.

Comment: The problem was updated.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution seems correct. However, it'd be much faster to simply notice that if $x,y\geq1$, $$154x+24y\geq178>30.$$

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the wording for this question.

Comment: @user23749 Possibly. As it stands, though, there exist integral solutions (as you’ve shown), but not positive integral ones.

Comment: I think whoever asked this question wanted to find integral solutions w/in a certain range or sth. I think it's a little fishy that this question has an answer a grade $1$ student could literally come up with. The real answer should use a similar approach to mine.

Comment: Listen! The question was updated! I used the approach above because I knew I would have to. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at 
$$
77+12=15
$$
right? For positive $x$ and $y$. 
Let $u = x-1, v = y-1$, then (1) $u$ and $v$ are nonnegative, and (2)

$$
77x + 12 y = 77 + 12 + (77u + 12 v) = 89 + (77u + 12v)
$$
which is at least $89$, because each of $u$ and $v$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Sorry. I think there's something wrong with the question. It should not be so simple that a grade $1$ student could solve it.

Comment: $x = 3, y = -18$.

Comment: Much as I usually find you're right on point, @DavidG.Stork, the number $-18$ is definitely not positive as required in the question. :)

Comment: Ah yes....  I don't think there's a solution for $\{ x, y \} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.... at least none I can find.  But $x \to 15/154, y \to 5/8$ for $\{ x,y \} \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the "+" in this problem was supposed to be a "-", which then makes it more interesting.

Comment: @JohnHughes the problem was updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

$x = 266; y = 2$ gives a solution, so evidently your current solution (to the most weirdly edited problem ever!) is wrong.